# Vue.js: How to retrieve data from API for vue chart.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

As I have no experience with drawing charts, using vue-chart.js for my project can be not very understandable.

I receive this data from API:

```
reports: {

 stats: {

  2018-02: {
    users: {
      "min": 12481,
      "max": 12581,
      "length": 19,
      "average": 12531,
      "median": 12527 
     }
    },
 2018-03: {
  users: {    
    "average": 12590,   
    "length": 1,
    "max": 12590,       
    "median": 12590,
    "min": 12590
   }
  } 
 }
}
```

I need to draw a chart showing the amount of active users in the system on every month. So the only parameter I need is `median`.

So far, my chart looks like this (I took this from examples of vue-chart.js):

```
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs';

export default {
extends: Line,
mounted () {
this.renderChart({
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Data One',
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',
      data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]
    }
   ]
  }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
 }
};
```

How can I send `median` values to the `data` parameter of the chart? I have the action `loadFullReport` and the getter `getFullReport`. Using the last one I can retrieve all the data from `report` object which you saw above.

Here is what I have in store:

```
import api from '../api';

export default {
state: {
  report: {
   isLoaded: false,
   data: {},
  },
},
actions: {
  loadFullReport({ commit }) {
  api
    .get('/reports/active', { params: { start_date: '2018-01-01', end_date: '2018-03-01' } })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      commit('SET_FULL_REPORT', data);
    });
  },
 },
mutations: {
  SET_FULL_REPORT(state, data) {
    state.report = {
      isLoaded: true,
      data,
    };
  },
},
 getters: {
   getFullReport(state) {
    return state.report;
  },
 },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your question. You have to transform your data, to fit the schema of chart.js

You can however add multiple datasets. The question is what are you trying to achieve.

```
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs';

export default {
extends: Line,
mounted () {
this.renderChart({
  labels: ['2018-02', '2018-03'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'umin',
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',
      data: [12481, 12590]
    },
    {
      label: 'umax',
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',
      data: [12581, 12590]
    },
    {
      label: 'umedian',
      backgroundColor: '#f87979',
      data: [12527, 12590]
    }
   ]
  }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
 }
};
```

The `labels:` array is your X axis.
The `data` array in your datasets object, is your Y value for the corresponding X value.

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║         ║ 2018-02    ║ 2018-03     ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ umin    ║ 12481      ║ 12590       ║
║ umax    ║ 12581      ║ 12590       ║
║ umedian ║ 12527      ║ 12590       ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```